# How to implement bi-directional FTP transfer in java

Tags: java, android, ftp

I need to implement bi-directional FTP transfer. Means I need to implement download/upload data at once. Like upload one packet and download it.

Please help me how can I do it by using FTP protocol. Any links to code or applications which have implemented this feature will help a lot.

Comment: I don't think ftp is the protocol for that. I maybe wrong. This is more of sockets stuff

Comment: You need to create two separate FTP objects / sessions, and use them in parallel. A single FTP session cannot do both at once.

Comment: From [RFC959](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959): "the data connection may be used for simultaneous sending and
      receiving." What are you having problems with?